# Display json data from post jquery

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, html

Hello im using a login script with ajax and i want to callback and display my data 
`email` and `usernam` to stock it in local storage.
i can get the data in json but i want to display this data in console.log

this is my codes

send_ajax.js

```
   $(document).ready(function(e) {
$("#contactSubmitButton").click(function(){
        var email    = $("#contactEmailField").val();
        var password = $("#contactNameField").val();

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://hubafrica.co/webservices/get_user.php",
    data: "email="+email+"&password="+password,
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,

    beforeSend: function(){ $("#contactSubmitButton").val('Chargement...');},

    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);

        if(data)
        {

             iterateJson(data);
             var url="http://hubafrica.co/webservices/get_user.php";

                    $.get(url,function(data){

                    // loop through the members here

                    $.each(json.data,function(i,dat){

                        console.log(dat.email);

                        window.localStorage.setItem("id", dat.id);


                    });

                  });



        //window.location.href = "user_dashboard.html";

        }else{

            $("#formSuccessMessageWrap").fadeIn('slow');
            $("#contactSubmitButton").val('se connecter');



        }


    },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {


      }
      });
    });
});
```

script.php

```
<?php 

header("Content-Type:application/json");

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

include("../config/config.php");

$account=array();

if (isset($_POST["email"])){

                $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST["email"]);
                $pass =  htmlspecialchars($_POST["password"]);
                    $sql = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `b2b_user` where email="'.$email.'" and password="'.$pass.'"');
                    $num = mysql_num_rows($sql);

                    if($num > 0){


                        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
                        $account['id']  = $row['id'];
                        $account['email'] = $row['email'];
                        echo '{"members":'.json_encode($account).'}';

                    }

            }
?>
```

Comment: feel frr to format your code a little..

Comment: try using `alert(JSON.stringify(data));`

Answer (score 1):

be for send response from backend you need to formate your data in json. Once you get in response you need to parseJSON()and the you can menuplate.

Answer (score 0):

change here:use `data.members` to access data:

in your **php** construct like this:do not append string.

```
 $account1= array('members'=>$account);
 echo json_encode($account1);
```

**script:**

```
$.each(data.members,function(i,dat){

                        console.log(dat.email);

                        window.localStorage.setItem("id", dat.id);


                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use

```
 alert(JSON.stringify(data));
```

or

```
 Console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Following line of code turns an object/array in to a JSON text and stores that JSON text in a string.

```
 JSON.stringify('/array variable here/')
```

Hope it helps.